# Integer pointers to a function

Tags: function, pointers

I have a dumb question. I'm trying to write a program that will get two numbers from a function and send them back to the main, where I can use them. However, when I run the code below, the only values returned are always zero. Should I change my pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get(int *num1, int *num2);

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, input;
    get(&num1, &num2);

    printf("Num1 is %d and num2 is %d.\n", num1, num2);
    return 0;
}

void get(int *num1, int *num2)
{
    printf("Enter two numbers. \n");
    printf("Number 1: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Number 2: \n");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("In function, %d and %d.\n", num1, num2);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, there are *no* dumb questions. Well, there are, but this isn't one of them :-)

In `get`, the `num1` and `num2` variables are *already* pointers to the integers, you shouldn't prefix them with `&`.

However, you *should* dereference the pointers in the `printf` within the function. See the following code for how to do it (along with some cosmetic changes not really relevant to the question at hand).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get(int *num1, int *num2) {
    printf("Enter two numbers.\n");

    printf("Number 1: ");
    scanf("%d", num1);                                   // << No &

    printf("Number 2: ");
    scanf("%d", num2);                                   // << No &

    printf("In function, %d and %d.\n", *num1, *num2);   // Add *'s
}

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, input;
    get(&num1, &num2);
    printf("Num1 is %d and num2 is %d.\n", num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
Enter two numbers.
Number 1: 5
Number 2: 8
In function, 5 and 8.
Num1 is 5 and num2 is 8.
```

Answer (score 1):

num1 and num2 inside the function are already pointers.

so inside scanf change &num1 to num1 and &num2 to num2.

```
#include <stdio.h>


void get(int *num1, int *num2);

int main(void)
{
    int num1, num2, input;
    get(&num1, &num2);

    printf("Num1 is %d and num2 is %d.\n", num1, num2);
    return 0;
}

void get(int *num1, int *num2)
{
    printf("Enter two numbers. \n");
    printf("Number 1: \n");
    scanf("%d", num1);

    printf("Number 2: \n");
    scanf("%d", num2);
    printf("In function, %d and %d.\n", num1, num2);

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning values to the *pointers*, not to the things they point to. Try either this:

```
scanf("%d", num1);
```

or **(in C++)** this:

```
void get(int &num1, int & num2)
{
  ...
  printf("Number 1: \n");
  scanf("%d", &num1);
  ...
  return;
}

int main(void)
{
  ...    
  get(num1, num2);
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That second sample is C++ rather than C, no? Or were references added to c1x?